# Issue with tcp connection not return same byte result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I have an issue with Tcp connection request. I have two applications, one is an Asp.net website and the other one is the Asp.net WebApi project. The Api is used to expose the same functionality used by the web for a mobile application. My Issue is that, there is a method that request a pdf file over a tcp connection and return pdf response. When am testing the web application i get the correct byte response but when am testing with the Api I am not receiving all the bytes. What could be the cause of this variation?.

"RequestData is an xml string with parameters to generate the pdf on the other side"

Here is the peace of code that is do tcp request.

```
 public static string Connect(string requestData)
        {
            // Create all required object and variables
            TcpClient tcpConnect = new TcpClient();
            NetworkStream tcpStream = null;
            string responseData = string.Empty;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int resLength = 0;
            using (tcpConnect)
            {
                try
                {

                    tcpConnect.Connect(hostAddress, hostPort);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }

                // Open TCP stream and send data
                using (tcpStream = tcpConnect.GetStream())
                {

                    byte[] reqBuffer =  Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO8859-1").GetBytes(requestData);

                    // Get the Big Endian representation of the length as a byte array.
                    byte[] lenBuffer = new byte[4];
                    lenBuffer[0] = (byte)((reqBuffer.Length & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
                    lenBuffer[1] = (byte)((reqBuffer.Length & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                    lenBuffer[2] = (byte)((reqBuffer.Length & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                    lenBuffer[3] = (byte)(reqBuffer.Length & 0x000000FF);

                    // Send length of request as Big Endian byte array
                    tcpStream.Write(lenBuffer, 0, lenBuffer.Length);

                    // Send request data as string
                    tcpStream.Write(reqBuffer, 0, reqBuffer.Length);

                    // Read 4 Bytes from the buffer, unless the socket is closed
                    bytesRead = 0;

                        bytesRead = tcpStream.Read(lenBuffer, bytesRead, lenBuffer.Length);



                    // If the number of bytes returned is 0 then throw an exception
                    if (bytesRead != 4)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unable to communicate with server or invalid data received");
                    }

                    // Get the length of the response byte array from a Big Endian representation.
                    resLength = (lenBuffer[0] << 24) + (lenBuffer[1] << 16) +
                                         (lenBuffer[2] << 8) + lenBuffer[3];

                    // Keep reading from the socket into the buffer until we have the specified number of bytes.
                    byte[] resBuffer = new byte[resLength];

                    // Read 4 Bytes from the buffer, unless the socket is closed
                    bytesRead = 0;
// Issue is here on this below while loop. the web app will receive more than 30 000 bytesread and APi get 3 000 and this result to an api receiving a blank pdf
                    while (bytesRead < resBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        bytesRead += tcpStream.Read(resBuffer, bytesRead, resBuffer.Length - bytesRead);
                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // If the number of bytes returned is 0 then throw an exception
                    if (bytesRead != resLength)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unable to communicate with server or invalid data received");
                    }

                    // Convert the response to valid string
                    responseData = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(resBuffer);

                    // Close the stream
                    tcpStream.Close();
                }

                // Close the connection
                tcpConnect.Close();
            }

            // Dispose of all objects
            tcpConnect = null;
            tcpStream = null;`enter code here`

            // Return result data
            return responseData;
        }
```

Comment: Where are you using webapi? I don't see any http clients. It seems you are using pure TCP sockets.

Comment: The mobile app is consuming Api so I i didn't post the code. But thanks i found that the is nothing wrong with code. May Api method is Get with accepted  querystring parameters and one of my parameter was guid with some "+" in it and they were ignore by and ended up passing a wrong value to my method

Comment: When it is going to stop reading? I still don't get how that works. Can you check my answer and comment it? When "break" is going to be called?

Answer (score 0):

That should not work at all because bytesRead will be 0 ONLY first time. So, I am not sure how it works with your Asp web site unless it is different code.

```
bytesRead += tcpStream.Read(resBuffer, bytesRead, resBuffer.Length - bytesRead);
if (bytesRead == 0)
{
    break;
}
```

What you should do is:

```
int bRead = tcpStream.Read(resBuffer, bytesRead, resBuffer.Length - bytesRead);
    if (bRead == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
bytesRead += bRead;
```

Comment: It will only execute that if statement if read returns 0bytes and break the look. But it will continue to read while bysteRead <   resBuffer.Length. If its equal to length then we no that there no bytes to read ..

Comment: @sipho thank you for your comment but I am afraid you are mistaken. This break will be never executed. Here is the test I suggest you to do. Start transferring big file and in the middle of transfer turn off your server. At this moment on client you either will get unhandled exception or endless loop of tcpStream.Read().